# How do I load configuration file on startup

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, configuration

I have `application.conf` file for my Scala program in `main/resources`. I load the configuration file using `Config.load()`. It is all working. But my config loading code is inside my service class. I want something like when program starts then first thing it doing is loading configuration. Then I want to use DI to pass this around.

This is easy in Scala Play because I just write Module class and specify in config file. Play then loads my config at start up. But how can I do this with non-Play project - just plain scala program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play uses [Guice](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Dependency-Injection) out-of-the-box for dependency injection, so you could consider using the same. 
Here is an example of how guice can be used to inject configuration into services:

```
package example

import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Guice, Inject, Injector, Provides, Singleton}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

case class Config(foo: String, bar: String)

class Module extends AbstractModule {
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  def getConfig: Config = {
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
    Config(
      conf.getString("foo"),
      conf.getString("bar")
    )
  }
}

class QuxService @Inject()(config: Config) {
  println(config)
}

object ConfigInjectionExample extends App {
  val injector: Injector = Guice.createInjector(List(new Module).asJava)
  injector.getInstance(classOf[QuxService])
}
```

which outputs

```
Config(hello,world)
```

given the following `resources/application.conf`

```
foo="hello"
bar="world"
```

and the following dependencies

```
libraryDependencies += "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.2.6",
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.4"
```

Comment: How is Module class loaded? When it loading? Is it automatic and at the beginning when I start my main method?

Comment: Yes it is instantiated inside the main method. Note how injector is created.